# Unable to connect to localhost:2525

Tags: php, gmail, localhost, port, laravel-8

i'm trying to send email using google mail and i'm having this error i tried doing it with mailtrap it gaves me the same error

> `Connection could not be established with host localhost :stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to localhost:2525 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)`
> i don't know whats the relation between the localhost and the port 2525, i'm not trying to use the port this is my `.env` file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=************************
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https:****************************

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=superett_super
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465  
MAIL_USERNAME=brick98sa@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=brick98sa@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

and this is my `config/mail.php` file i have already tried to change the host and the port in this file nothing works

```
<?php

return [
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],

        'failover' => [
            'transport' => 'failover',
            'mailers' => [
                'smtp',
                'log',
            ],
        ],
    ],

'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Is that `MAIL_PASSWORD` your real password?

Comment: ofc not real it's just for test xd